# How to write query for group with in the alphabetical range

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have list of topics and need to display those topics within the alphabetical group range.

```
public class Topic
            {
                public string Title { get; set; }
            }
    List<Topic> topics = new List<Topic>();
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Egg" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Blue" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Adeno" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Elephant" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Air" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Fun" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Fish" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Care" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Deer" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "African" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Cook" });
                topics.Add(new Topic() { Title = "Flow" });
```

I have tried following but this will return for each individual alphabets A-Z.

```
var sortedGroups =
    from topic in topics 
    orderby topic.Title
    group topic by topic.Last[0] into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;
foreach (var tGroup in sortedGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tGroup.Key);
    foreach (var t in tGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.Title);
    }
}
```

Desired Output looks like

- ABC

  - Adeno
  - African
  - Air
  - Blue
  - Cook
  - Care
- DEF

  - Deer
  - Egg
  - Elephant
  - Fun
  - Fish
  - Flow
- GHI
- JKL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know this is ugly, but it works.....

```
    var q = from t in topics
            orderby t.Title
            group t by (((int)t.Title[0])+1) /3;
```

- `(int)t.Title[0])`  - Turns the first letter into a number.  ("A" = 65, "B"=66, ...)
- `+1`   - Correction to make the groups right ("A" is now 66, "B" = 67 etc)
- `/3`   - Gives three consecutive letters the same value(A,B,C now = 22)